# Add a filter to hide negative scoring questions

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, filtering, question-lists

There are more and more people that don't write a proper question these days. When I find some question to answer I often end up flagging bad posts. (And when my flags are depleted, I run away.)

Basically, in my experience a question with -1 is somewhat hard to answer and -2 is definitely unacceptable. It would be good to add a filter to hide them (there are only answer count based filters now).

Comment: There is too much abuse potential in this. Just think about it: Everybody using your proposed filter could not see your feature request now and vote for it.

Comment: Downvote on Meta is different, and I'm not proposing that as a useful thing on meta.

Comment: Sure, Meta is different. But what I was aiming at is independent from this: The first vote has too much power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I find for some question to answer I often end up flagging bad posts.

How would you see those questions and take the appropriate action if you didn't see them any more? What about spam? They would only receive one flag and then nothing more.

Often users forget that Stack Exchange sides work both ways: you need to put something in to get something back. Just filtering on 'good' questions will make 'bad' questions sit around forever. Also, 'bad' questions in need of some help won't get the attention to turn them around.

And, as Wrzlprmft said in a comment: *The first vote has too much power.*

Answer (score 4):

You can already do this with search. Simply search for [`score:0.. is:q`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a0..%20is%3aq).